# Changing directories in Spyder 3.5

Tags: directory, spyder

I just updated my copy of Spyder on my Windows XP desktop to Spyder 3.5. How do I change directories so that the working directory is the one (in a subfolder in My documents)in which I have my Python Script and .txt data files (e.g. for running a regression)?

Comment: Did you try `cd <path-to-your-dir>` in the IPython console?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I'm using the latest Spyder.  I wanted my files to be in other than my home directory.   I tried setting the current directory in Preferences.  My files still wound up in my home directory.  I tried the "cd" command.  It said that the current directory was the one I wanted, but still the files were written to my home directory.

So I saved my script file in the directory I wanted.  Now my files go where I would like.